# WebBrowser selected text is not working

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to get the selected text from a html document but I have a problem with my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            wb.Navigate(@"D:\s\1.html");



                if (wb.Document != null)
                {
                    IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = wb.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;

                    IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = htmlDocument.selection;


                    if (currentSelection != null)
                    {
                        IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;

                        if (range != null)
                        {
                            textBox1.Text = range.text;
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it sais `ArgumentException was unhandeled` for this:

```
IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
```

I would apprecate if someone could send me a working code or help me somehow in my problem.

Comment: what happes when you debug the code can you determine if you are missing something and or doing something incorrectly

Comment: I'm new in forms so may i have done something wrong.
Should I upload my solution, so you can check it?

Comment: I realised it has a problem with my .html so I changed it to a web page, and it runs, but still goes nothing to my textbox.

Comment: have you stepped through the code using the debugger you need to do that and inspect the variables / objects to see if any data is even being populated in your range variable

Comment: Sorry for asking this question but it took me 6 hours to figure it out that I made a terrible mistake with a tag in my html file so the webbrowswer still could display it but I cannot convert it.
Also I forgot to put the whole code into an event.